# Google Cloud SQL JSON object aggregate

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Since Google Cloud SQL only supports MySQL 5.7.14, I cannot use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to group `JSON_OBJECT()`. I resorted to using `GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT())`, however, I discovered that `GROUP_CONCAT` has a character limit of `1025` based on the official docs.

Has anyone found a workaround to create large JSON arrays using MySQL 5.7.14?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You might have to write a UDF if you really want to do this in your version of MySQL.  Or, you can always handle this in your application layer, using something like Java or C#.

Comment: Also the documentation explains how to make that limit larger. You will have to execute `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` before running your query, then it should work just fine on your MySQL version.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Missed that part. Thanks. Maybe I'll just increase it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland 's comment is right. Can you post it as an answer, Raymond, please? [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) explains how to make that limit larger. You will have to execute `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` before running your query, then it should work just fine on your MySQL version.